# Blaze persistence UpdatableEntityView as spring boot request body

Tags: spring-boot, blaze-persistence

I am trying to use blaze persistence UpdatableEntityView as the request body with spring boot.
Following is the code for UpdatableEntityView

```
@UpdatableEntityView
@EntityView(DealListing.class)
public interface DealListingUpdateView {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    void setId(Long id);

    Instant getListedOn();
    void setListedOn(Instant listedOn);
}
```

Following is the rest controller mapping

```
@PutMapping("/deal-listings/sell/{id}")
    public void test(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody DealListingUpdateView dealListingUpdateView){
        dealListingService.testUpdate(id, dealListingUpdateView);
}
```

Following is the pom.xml dependency to do the deserialization as specified in the blaze persistence document

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.blazebit</groupId>
            <artifactId>blaze-persistence-integration-jackson</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

But when i submit the request i am getting the following error

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class com.ilex.tradeservice.domain.view.blaze.DealListingUpdateView]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.ilex.tradeservice.domain.view.blaze.DealListingUpdateView` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation, you will need the Spring Data WebMvc integration: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-webmvc-integration

You will also have to additionally annotate your controller parameter with `@EntityViewId("id")`

```
@PutMapping("/deal-listings/sell/{id}")
public void test(@PathVariable Long id, @EntityViewId("id") @RequestBody DealListingUpdateView dealListingUpdateView){
        dealListingService.testUpdate(id, dealListingUpdateView);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i did this but after adding this dependency i am getting some exception so i have removed it.
Let me add and study the exception again to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: If you can share some details I can maybe help you, but you can also try one of the quickstarts to compare what you might be missing: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#quickstart

Comment: I managed to make it work. Just putting here so it may help others. Actually i missed the following dependency.

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.blazebit</groupId>
            <artifactId>blaze-persistence-integration-spring-data-2.4</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>



By the way i noticed that when update happens its not triggering the hibernate/jpa callback events such as PreUpdate/PrePersist. Is it expected?

Comment: That is expected for the `QUERY` flush strategy, which is the default. You can switch to `@UpdatableEntityView(strategy = FlushStrategy.ENTITY)` if you need entity listeners to be called for update/remove operations, but this comes with a performance cost, so maybe you can make use of entity view listeners instead: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#lifecycle-and-listeners